# Как подключить сканер штрих-кодов к мобильному компьютеру?

Tags: android

Есть следующий мобильный компьютер со встроенным сканером штрих-кодов [ZKC PDA3501 GSM 3G WiFi RFID/NFC Android Mobile Portable 1D and 2D CMOS Barcode Scanner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jc1afaSJRP8):

> [image: Сканер]

Я хочу на него установить мое приложение, которое будет считывать данные со сканера и сохранять их в БД.

Но не знаю как подключиться к сканеру устройства и как, например, вывести результат в *TextView*. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

В Google удалось найти только возможные версии самих компьютеров *QS-3501-B* или *ZKC PDA3501*.

Comment: Проблему такая, есть мобильный компьютер со встроенным сканером штрих-кодов. Я хочу на него установить мое приложение, которое будет считывать данные со сканера и сохранять их в БД. Не знаю как подключиться к сканеру устройства и как, например, вывести результат в TextView. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой????

Comment: Вы не в комментарии пишите, а отредактируйте сам вопрос.

Comment: Он имел в виду, что если в комментарии написать `[edit]` не в блоке кода, то будет так: [edit]

Comment: А он не клавиатура?)

Comment: @AK, просто мне казалось, что сканеры штрихкодов обычно определяются компьютером как клавиатуры. По крайней мере те, которые в магазинах. Или нет?

Comment: @AK но пока ещё не ясно почему было написано на английском!

Comment: @alexolut, вроде ясно: традиционное перепутал сайт. Только с последующим "раз уж задал тут, то переведу".

Comment: @Qwertiy хотелось бы по шагам: где началось это перепутье!

Comment: @alexolut, ну 5 баллов он уже набрал - можно теперь отвечать на мете :)

Comment: что, никто не сталкивался с моей проблемой???

Comment: @dmorskoi, я никогда не работал со сканерами. alexolut - [тоже](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40074212#40074212).

Answer (score 0):

Качаете родное SDK c сайта производителя http://www.qsprinter.com/download.html.

Подключаете.

Запускаете движок сканнера:

```
CaptureService.scanGpio.openScan();
```

Создаете свой класс для получения баркодов (как текста) со сканнера:

```
class ScanBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String text = intent.getExtras().getString("code");
    Log.i("TAG", "MyBroadcastReceiver code:" + text);
    editText1.setText(text); 
      }
}
```

и регистрируете его через SDK:

```
private ScanBroadcastReceiver scanBroadcastReceiver;
scanBroadcastReceiver = new ScanBroadcastReceiver();
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("com.zkc.scancode");
this.registerReceiver(scanBroadcastReceiver,     
intentFilter);
```

Когда надоест сканнировать, закрываете движок и отписываетесь:

```
CaptureService.scanGpio.closeScan();
unregisterReceiver(scanBroadcastReceiver);
```

Comment: PashPash. Я возможно чего-то не понимаю, но как эту SDK подключить к проекту. В ней нету gradle.biuld. И ее не удается импортировать никакими способами. Она также не открывается обычным Open как проект. Точнее открывается, но ничего не компилется. Как вообще подключить такую SDK и пользоваться ею? Вопрос конечно глупый, но 2-ой день уже подключаю.... Возможно ли обычным Ctrl+c Ctrl+v это вставить в проект и потом gradle руками прописывать, или можно как еще?

Comment: @dmorskoi я не джавист и не андроид разработчик :). но вообще -скачал файл 3866451be4c430b3ad04b72c5697524a.7z, распаковал - в нем есть build.gradle и даже gradlew.bat для билда под винду